# g++ linking: multiple definition of function

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++

I've searched for a long time but people on the Internet said not to put function definition in header file. But i DIDNOT. And i looked over the questions on stackoverflow but they aren't similar with my case(in my opinion), so i hope that it's not a duplicate(or dumb) question.

I have a start() function, in() and out() function (all declared in settings.h), main.cpp calls start() and start() in utils.cpp calls in() and out(), which is in io.cpp.
It works fine all in a same file. But it fails when I seperate it.

main.cpp

```cpp
# include "settings.h"

int main()
{
    start(in, out, ">");
    return 0;
}
```

utils.cpp

```cpp
# include "settings.h"

void start(string(*in)(string), int (*out)(string), string test_msg)
{
    string test_answer;
    test_answer = in(test_msg);
    out(test_answer);
}
```

io.cpp

```cpp
#include "settings.h"

string in(string msg)
{
    out(msg);
    string ans;
    cin >> ans;
    return ans;
}

int out(string msg)
{
    cout << msg;
    return 0;
}
```

settings.h

```cpp
# ifndef SETTINGS_H
# define SETTINGS_H

# include <string>
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string in(string);
int out(string);
void start(string(*)(string), int (*)(string), string); // start function

# endif
```

I'm actually new to Linux and C++.
This is pretty basic stuff, so I am rather baffled.

shell

```bash
g++ -o ./bin/linuca   ./temp/utils.o  ./temp/io.o  ./temp/main.o
```

Actual error snippit:

```
./temp/io.o: In function `start(std::string (*)(std::string), int (*)(std::string), std::string)':
utils.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `start(std::string (*)(std::string), int (*)(std::string), std::string)'
./temp/utils.o:utils.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
./temp/main.o: In function `start(std::string (*)(std::string), int (*)(std::string), std::string)':
utils.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `start(std::string (*)(std::string), int (*)(std::string), std::string)'
./temp/utils.o:utils.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [linuca] Error 1
```

They were put in the dir below:
[the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQUVb.png)

Comment: Before invoking `g++ -o ./bin/linuca   ./temp/utils.o  ./temp/io.o  ./temp/main.o` you should rebuild all those .o files. The error informs about the previous file contents when you attempted #include "utils.cpp" file in io.cpp and main.cpp. Undefined reference to `main' also clearly says, main.o is obsolete and built from the previous main.cpp

Comment: Don't believe everything people say on the internet.  Some functions optimize extremely well as inline in their typical use cases.  Try, err, and find what works.

Comment: Show the *full* build, not just the link. Frankly, I'd delete every .o file in your source tree and build-anew.

Comment: @273K tried, sill not working.   I deleted all the *.o files and rebuilt it, but it give the same error message when linking.

Comment: See the comment right above your one.